Inconsistent bone movement with transformation and clamp to constraints
Arm rig uses 4 plates to cover the elbow and are currently rigged to move into the bicep as the forearm rotates on the Z-axis. The 4 bones that control these covers are clamped to a curve. In pose mode, rotating the forearm causes the 4 plate covers to move slightly away from the forearm but not into the bicep. Another issue is that in pose mode the bones cluster together and are overlapping as opposed to their rest position. Here's the forearm extended out:

And here's a slight angle:

2 issues to solve:

Have the Front_elbow_cover_bone_X bones match their Edit mode positions in pose mode when the forearm is extended initially.
How the Front_elbow_cover_bone_X bones should look when the forearm is extended in pose mode (taken from edit mode):

Fix the transformation constraint on those same bones to retract/extend the plates into/out of the bicep as the forearm bone rotates. Here's how the elbow should look as the forearm rotates inwards:




Did you have an actual question to ask with this post? I didn't see it. We can't as easily tell what "strange" or "bad" movement look like because we can't even tell what part of the mesh you're talking about or what the expected result is.

Updated post for better clarity

Actually, working on your issue it appears that the only problem is with the Bone Map To constraint, where each elbow_cover_bone X-source to Z-location Max value needed to be tuned.  Here on Front_elbow_cover_bone_4_l I tuned to:



I'm guessing you were only missing the required coffee break to think it through.  Nice technique, by the way!

It's always the smallest things you miss haha. Thanks!
